How to properly distinguish between horizontal scrolling and magnification gestures in SwiftUI with Charts?
I'm working on a graph interface in SwiftUI using the Swift Charts and I've implemented a magnification gesture to zoom (modify the x-axis values) using the MagnifyGesture. It partially works, but I also have horizontal scrolling enabled for the chart, which seems to conflict with the gesture recognition. When performing the gesture "vertically", it seems to be recognized much better. Here is my code:
import Charts
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
struct GraphScreen: View {
    @Environment(ThemeManager.self) private var theme
    @Environment(DataModel.self) private var dataModel: DataModel
    
    @State private var scrollPosition = Date()
    @State private var selectedPrice: CandlestickDataPoint?
    
    @State var investmentData: [CandlestickDataPoint] = []
    @State var minimum: Double = 0
    @State var maximum: Double = 1
    @State var minimumAdjusting: Double = 0.995
    @State var maximumAdjusting: Double = 1.005
    
    @State private var currentZoom = 0.0
    @State private var totalZoom = 24.0
    @State private var strideMinuteCount = 15
    @State private var barWidth: CGFloat = 10
    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .task {
                do {
                    let response = try await dataModel.userStock()
                    investmentData = ChartManager.shared.process(response: response)
                    totalZoom = 12
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: totalZoom, { oldValue, newValue in
                // Adjust the barWidth and strideMinuteCount based on the zoom level
                strideMinuteCount = Int(5 * newValue) // Adjust the stride count based on some formula
                barWidth = max(1, CGFloat(48 / newValue)) // Adjust the bar width
                
                let visibleData = getVisibleValues()
                setMinMax(forValues: visibleData)
            })
    }
    
    func getVisibleValues() -> [CandlestickDataPoint] {
        let minDate = scrollPosition
        let maxDate = scrollPosition.addingTimeInterval((currentZoom + totalZoom) * 1800)
        let values = investmentData.filter({ $0.date >= minDate && $0.date <= maxDate })
        return values
    }
    
    func setMinMax(forValues values: [CandlestickDataPoint]) {
        minimum = (values.map({ $0.low }).min() ?? 0) //* minimumAdjusting
        maximum = (values.map({ $0.high }).max() ?? 1) //* maximumAdjusting
    }
}

extension GraphScreen {
    var content: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            theme.selected.backgroundScreenColor
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                
                chart
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
    }
    
    var magnifyGesture: some Gesture {
        return MagnifyGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                currentZoom = 1 - value.magnification
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                totalZoom += currentZoom
                currentZoom = 0
                totalZoom = min(max(totalZoom, 1), 24)
            }
    }
    
    var chart: some View {
        Chart(investmentData) { item in
            
            BarMark(
                x: .value("Date", item.date),
                yStart: .value("Open", min(item.open, item.close)),
                yEnd: .value("Close", max(item.open, item.close)),
                width: .fixed(barWidth)
            )
            .foregroundStyle(item.close > item.open ? Color.green : Color.red)
            
            RuleMark(
                x: .value("Date", item.date),
                yStart: .value("Low", item.low),
                yEnd: .value("High", item.high)
            )
            .foregroundStyle(item.close > item.open ? Color.green : Color.red)
        }
        .chartYScale(domain: [minimum, maximum])
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(position: .automatic, values: .automatic) {
                AxisGridLine()
                    .foregroundStyle(theme.selected.bodyTextGrayColor)
                
                AxisValueLabel()
                    .foregroundStyle(theme.selected.bodyTextGrayColor)
            }
        }
        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .minute, count: strideMinuteCount)) {
                AxisGridLine()
                    .foregroundStyle(theme.selected.bodyTextGrayColor)
                
                AxisValueLabel()
                    .foregroundStyle(theme.selected.bodyTextGrayColor)
            }
        }
        //.disabled(true)
        .chartScrollableAxes([.horizontal])
        .chartScrollPosition(x: $scrollPosition)
        .onChange(of: scrollPosition) {
            print(scrollPosition)
            let visibleData = getVisibleValues()
            setMinMax(forValues: visibleData)
        }
        .chartXVisibleDomain(length: (currentZoom + totalZoom) * 1800)
        .chartGesture { chartProxy in
            magnifyGesture
        }
    }
}

When I disable the entire chart's interaction, the magnify gesture works well, but then I lose the horizontal scroll functionality and would need to implement it manually, potentially complicating other graph interactions.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to adjust or configure the gestures so they can coexist without interfering with each other?

Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

@Jay Nope. I started using 3rd party chart library.
